# handle 404 error in angular that throws from python when trying to download file from google drive

Tags: angular

```
window.location.href = environment.urls.baseUrl + this.fbApiConstants.API_URLS.private_build_url +
            '?id=' + app.build_id + '&token=' + token;
```

The above code redirect to initial a file download that store in google drive. if someone delete file from google drive the above call throws 404 error i need to properly handle error without breaking application in angular

Comment: What is the link with python ? What is the event triggering this redirection ? Would opening in a new tab being a solution ? Please tell us more about your code / behavior.

Comment: You can send a head request and check if response success than redirect your user

Comment: window.location.href = environment.urls.baseUrl + this.fbApiConstants.API_URLS.private_build_url +
            '?id=' + app.build_id + '&token=' + token;
this code initiate an api call which trigger file download from google drive